# Set linewidth of listings inside animation?

Tags: listings, width, animate

How can I set the `linewidth` of a `listings` if this is inside `animateinline`?
So far it seems that this setting is ignored in this situation. But it works outside the `animate`.

This seems to be another strange interaction between packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}{1}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{black!50},linewidth=6cm]
i = 1
\end{lstlisting}
\newframe
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{black!50},linewidth=6cm]
i = 2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{animateinline}

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{black!50},linewidth=6cm]
i = 3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Produces this (`i=1` is animated but not with the desired line width):

[image: animatelinewidth]

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put each frame content into a `minipage` of desired width and height, such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begingroup\parindent=0pt
\begin{animateinline}{1}
\begin{minipage}[\baselineskip]{6cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{black!50},linewidth=\linewidth]
i = 1
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\newframe
\begin{minipage}[\baselineskip]{6cm}
\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{black!50},linewidth=\linewidth]
i = 2
\end{lstlisting}
\end{minipage}
\end{animateinline}
\endgroup

\begin{lstlisting}[backgroundcolor=\color{black!50},linewidth=6cm]
i = 3
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Animation frames are put into LR boxes, which may screw up material that expects to be typeset in paragraph mode.

Comment: Thanks. I tried also omitting the second optional argument in `minipage` (the `[height]`) and strange things happened (scrambled! frames in Acrobat 9.4.1).